# How should I indent ternary conditional operator in python so that it complies with PEP8?

Tags: python, formatting, pep8, ternary

PEP8 doesn't say anything about ternary operators, if I am not mistaken.
So what do you suggest, how should I write long lines with ternary conditional operators?

```
some_variable = some_very_long_value \
                if very_long_condition_holds \
                else very_long_condition_doesnt_hold
```

or

```
some_variable = some_very_long_value \
                    if very_long_condition_holds \
                        else very_long_condition_doesnt_hold
```

Which one do you prefer the most?

Comment: The first is more readible. Btw there is a pep8 program that will check your python files. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pep8

Comment: (1) PEP 8 prefers parentheses over backslashes for expressions spanning several lines. (2) You could always not use the operator if the condition and values are so long.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions asking for opinions on something are not on-topic for Stack Overflow. There are several other places where these questions might get a better reception; you should try there instead.

Answer (score 20):

Neither. For any long line, it's usually better to use parentheses to allow line breaks. Opinions differ whether you should do this:

```
some_variable = (some_very_long_value
                if very_long_condition_holds
                else very_long_condition_doesnt_hold)
```

or this:

```
some_variable = (
    some_very_long_value
    if very_long_condition_holds
    else very_long_condition_doesnt_hold)
```

or even this:

```
some_variable = (
    some_very_long_value
    if very_long_condition_holds
    else very_long_condition_doesnt_hold
)
```

Personally I prefer the third; Google in-house style is the second.

Answer (score 5):

```
some_variable = (some_very_long_value
                 if very_long_condition_holds else
                 very_long_condition_doesnt_hold)
```

- Use parentheses instead of backslashes for line continuations, per PEP8.
- By putting the `if ... else` construct on its own line, there's a clear separation between the three parts of this expression: the `then` expression, the conditional part, and the `else` expression.  The `then` and `else` expressions are formatted uniformly and are separate from the `if...else` construct.

Answer (score 1):

```
some_variable = some_very_long_value\
                if very_long_condition_holds\
                else othervalue
```

prefer braces when face such problems.
check about Maximum Line Length here. http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length

Comment: Braces? Or do you mean parentheses?

Comment: @PM2Ring `SyntaxError: not a chance`